# Finding nearest point for each distinct category in performant way using big PostGIS table?

Tags: postgis, sql, performance, knn

I have a table, `etablissements` with millions of rows, and a `geom` (st_point) column , spatially indexed (using gist).
Those features may have a different category, `activite_principale`.

I want to find from a given, fixed point the closest companies for 5 or 6 different categories called "activite_principale" (1 closest company per category).

Here's what I did right now:

```
    (WITH closest_candidates AS (
      SELECT
        ent.id,
        ent.name,
        ent.geom
      FROM
        geo_data.etablissements ent
      WHERE ent.activite_principale = '1071C'
      ORDER BY
        ent.geom <->
        'SRID=4326;POINT (5.4153978921979125 43.271437384501965)'::geometry
      LIMIT 10
    )
    SELECT id
    FROM closest_candidates
    ORDER BY
      ST_Distance(
        geom,
        'SRID=4326;POINT (5.4153978921979125 43.271437384501965)'::geometry
        )
    LIMIT 1)
    UNION ALL
    (WITH closest_candidates AS (
      SELECT
        ent.id,
        ent.name,
        ent.geom
      FROM
        geo_data.etablissements ent
      WHERE ent.activite_principale = '4711D'
      ORDER BY
        ent.geom <->
        'SRID=4326;POINT (5.4153978921979125 43.271437384501965)'::geometry
      LIMIT 10
    )
    SELECT id
    FROM closest_candidates
    ORDER BY
      ST_Distance(
        geom,
        'SRID=4326;POINT (5.4153978921979125 43.271437384501965)'::geometry
        )
    LIMIT 1)

--   UNION ALL
-- [...]  And so on...
```

I then clustered the etablissements table around the geom spatial index and ran `VACUUM ANALYZE geo_data.etablissements;`

[Here's the result of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` after clustering.](https://gist.github.com/kofronpi/20254f188409b364ba1916c5e8444fc9)

The planning is much shorter and the execution too but it's still slow (350-450ms).

I investigated compound index on geom & another text column, but that does not seem to be possible today ?

I use postgres 10 & postgis 2.4.

I don't know how to improve based on those explanations from the query planner. Can I do better performance ?

Comment: In general, if you have working code, and want it reviewed for performance, then the place to ask is the [codereview.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: @PolyGeo I think the GIS community is more focused on those kind of performance issues based on KNN search ?

Comment: If you have a UNION ALL query cascade which is returning subsecond results, there isn't anything we can do. What kind of performance are you expecting?

Comment: I think the GIS community would ask questions about such performance issues at the [codereview.se] Stack Exchange, or maybe float them in the GIS Chat Room.

Comment: dude, what kind of machine are you on? you are running a KNN search on 'millions of rows' to find the 10 nearest points, then running a second KNN search to find the closest one of that set (this is bogus, just find the closest one in the first place!?)...and you are doing that 5 times with a cascading UNION in under half a second? if you don´t want to do this 1000 times in a row, where´s the problem? ,)

Comment: @ThingumaBob I invite you to read this article : http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/knn.html. I am not doing two knn searchs. KNN returns approximative results which is fine because it's fast, then filtering by ST_Distance is only to find the closest one in a proven way. I'm using heroku postgres and this is the "standard-0" plan for prototyping, I will upgrade in the future. Do you think the performance is already good ?

Comment: @Vince I'm not convinced my cascading UNION ALL is the best solution, that's why I'm asking. My problem : how to find the X closest points of table Y with distinct Z categories, and you are guaranteed each row is the closest X for category Z.

Comment: @PolyGeo thanks for your feedback. I will ask my question there too.

Comment: @Pak I see, you're on PostGIS 2.4 (`<->` returns true distance from 2.5 on); still, if it's point-to-point, bbox comparison equals true distance (I'm sure that's noted in the article somewhere). I'm going to post a query that I'm curious to see the speed for on your system...

Comment: @PolyGeo would ArcPy code go on CodeReview.SE?

Comment: @DPSSpatial if it is seeking a code review then I think it should. I think there is a Meta GIS Q&A saying that which I'll try to find in a moment.

Comment: @DPSSpatial https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4305/115 is what I was thinking of - it does not mention ArcPy but I'm sure the question came from an ArcPy user who had been asking for their code to be reviewed.

Comment: @PolyGeo if someone posted a similar question that dealt with ArcPy code, I don't think it would be treated the same way. The question is not seeking code review - it is seeking advice on the implementation of the logic as it relates to the size of the datasets involved. I don't to harp too much on this subject, as I do with others, but your profile/tags suggest you're more of an ArcGIS expert, so I wonder why would you come to this post to suggest how the answer should be discovered?

Comment: @DPSSpatial The reason I comment on, vote on or edit any post is always the same. It is to try and get as many questions asked on the SE network answered as possible by trying to make them as focused as possible. Sometimes there is more than one site that should be considered when deciding to post. Here I am trying to assist that choice. Note that I have not voted to close the question. If I felt certain that it did not belong here I would have.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/191967/knn-search-by-distinct-category-in-postgis-postgres

Comment: I also made the experience that PostGIS sometimes computes an inefficient query plan. The approach to use a CTE to select candidates based on KNN is not always possible, specifically if the limit would need to be very high for sparsely populated categories. For those, filtering on category first and by KNN second sometimes is more efficient. The hard question is how to judge which plan is better. Ideally the query planner should handle this but it looks like it's off in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

I´m curious, what does your plan say if you run

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.activite_principale)
       a.activite_principale,
       a.id
FROM geo_data.etablissements AS a
WHERE a.activite_principale IN ('1071C', '4711D', <3rd>, <4th>, <5th>)
ORDER BY a.activite_principale,
         a.geom <-> 'SRID=32632;POINT(363982.8087 5623158.5124)'::geometry
```

(Fill in `<3rd>`, `<4th>`, `<5th>`)

Comment: Around 1 s for 4 categories : https://gist.github.com/kofronpi/4b1fba2d4cdfbfbaa6880e69482274f2

Comment: @Pak doesn´t care much for your clustering maybe?...if I run your query and mine on the same test data (500k points, 4 categories, *[name, id, geom]* columns in select), with equal results, the plan for your query does include *Index (only) scans* on all four subqueries (contrary to *Heap Scans* in your plan; did you rund `ANALYZE geo_data.etablissements` prior to running the queries?), but still takes about double to triple the time on average than my query above...

Comment: I ran analyze after clustering. That's really interesting. Might be the clustering, did you try after clustering by geom ? I will look into it

Comment: @Pak also, try your query without the CTEs and by selecting the nearest neighbor directly (*KNN* + `LIMIT 1`) (btw, my table wasn't clustered)

Comment: it seems to be better ! I will benchmark it.